# How to print class object using operator<<

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, iostream

I want to write a print function for a class AutoData that has information about cars in it. With this print function, I would ideally like to print out a vector that contains many different class objects. I have already written get functions for each element of the objects, but I am still a bit unsure of how to go about using those to write a function to print out the data in the following format:

```
mpg:cylinders:displacement:horsepower:weight:acceleration:modelYear:origin:carName
```

For example:

```
10.0:8:360.0:215.0:4615.:14.0:70:1:ford f250
10.0:8:307.0:200.0:4376.:15.0:70:1:chevy c20
11.0:8:318.0:210.0:4382.:13.5:70:1:dodge d200
```

The class is:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AutoData {

public:
    AutoData()
    {
        mpg = 0;
        cylinders = 0;
        displacement = 0;
        horsepower = 0;
        weight = 0;
        acceleration = 0;
        modelYear = 0;
        origin = 0;
        carName = "";
    }

    AutoData( const AutoData & rhs)
    {
        setAuto(rhs.mpg, rhs.cylinders, rhs.displacement, rhs.horsepower, rhs.weight, rhs.acceleration, rhs.modelYear, rhs.origin, rhs.carName);
    }

    void setAuto(float mp, int cy, float di, float ho, float we, float ac, int mo, int o, string ca)
    {
        mpg = mp;
        cylinders = cy;
        displacement = di;
        horsepower = ho;
        weight = we;
        acceleration = ac;
        modelYear = mo;
        origin = o;
        carName = ca;
    }

    const float & getmpg( ) const
    {
        return mpg;
    }

    const int & getcylinders( ) const
    {
        return cylinders;
    }

    const float & getdisplacement( ) const
    {
        return displacement;
    }

    const float & gethorsepower( ) const
    {
        return horsepower;
    }

    const float & getweight( ) const
    {
        return weight;
    }

    const float & getacceleration( ) const
    {
        return acceleration;
    }

    const int & getmodelYear( ) const
    {
        return modelYear;
    }

    const int & getorigin( ) const
    {
        return origin;
    }

    const string & getcarName( ) const
    {
        return carName;
    }

    bool operator == (const AutoData & rhs ) const
    {
        if( getmpg( ) == rhs.getmpg( ) )
        {
            return gethorsepower( ) == rhs.gethorsepower( );
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool operator > ( const AutoData & rhs ) const
    {
        if( rhs.getmpg( ) > getmpg( ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if( getmpg( ) == rhs.getmpg( ) )
        {
            if( rhs.gethorsepower( ) > gethorsepower( ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


private:
    float mpg;
    int cylinders;
    float displacement;
    float horsepower;
    float weight;
    float acceleration;
    int modelYear;
    int origin;
    string carName;
};
```

Any help/advice anyone can provide would be very much appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: if you want to print to console just cout << mpg << ":" << cylinders << ":" etc - if you want to store in a string use a stringstream.

Comment: but how would i print out an entire vector of these?
so that its 
mpg1:cylinders1:etc...
mpg2:cylinders2:etc...

Comment: Just iterate over the vector and add newlines between the entries

Comment: what I said would be in its own method, then just iterate through each vector using a ranged based for loop like you would normally.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to be able to do `std::cout << AutoData();`, you need to overload the output stream operator `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, AutoData const& data) {
    out << data.getmpg() << ':';
    out << data.getcylinders() << ':';
    // and so on... 
    return out;
}
```

This function is not a member function, and since you have getters for each attribute, you do not have to declare this function as `friend` of your class.

Then you can do:

```
AutoData myAuto;
std::cout << myAuto << '\n';
```

Comment: I find the `const&` notation very confusing (distracts from the fact that is the underlying `AutoData` that is `const`, not the reference), but other than that, it seems we started to type the same answer at the same time :D but I was slower, because I tried to do `operator>>` too...
Ah, and I would insert `std::endl` in `operator<<` so I could guarantee that I can read `carName` with `std::readline` in `operator>>` ...

Comment: @Massa I'm used to use `cons&`, but maybe you're right for a beginner it could be confusing. Concerning `std::endl`, I think it shouldn't be in the `operator<<`, because you could want to put multiple `AutoData` on the same line, separated by coma / tab. It depends on what you really needs.

Comment: my reasoning is that if you don't define a (default?) terminator for `AutoData::carName` and enforce it on `operator<<`, then `operator>>` cannot know where the record ends. That's why I would've settled for the simpler option of terminating the record with `endl` and using `readline` to read the final string. Other option would be to put the terminator in a `static` member of `AutoData` and matching reads and writes using it....

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried so far? My approach would be overloading `operator<<`, like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const AutoData& dasAuto) {
  return out << dasAuto.getmpg() << ':' << dasAuto.getcylinders() <<
    /* insert everthing in the desired order here */
    std::endl;
}
```

And the same thing for the "reading" function, like:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, AutoData& dasAuto) {
  float mpg;
  int cylinders;
  float displacement;
  float horsepower;
  float weight;
  float acceleration;
  int modelYear;
  int origin;
  string carName;
  char separator;
  const char SEP = ':';

  if( !(in >> mpg >> separator) || (separator != SEP) ) return in;
  if( !(in >> cylinders >> separator) || (separator != SEP) ) return in;
    /* rinse, repeat */
  if( !std::getline(in, carName) ) return in;
  dasAuto.setAuto(mpg, cylinders /*, etc etc */);
  return in;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, `auto` is a reserved keyword in C++ 11.

Comment: @Holt -- it slipped my mind... it's 06:30 here, I was probably half-asleep :D

Answer (score 3):

You can read this artical to know about `friend` and `operator <<`,
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

In the class `AutoData`, you should declare this function:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const AutoData& obj);
```

outside the class, you should define this function like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const AutoData& obj)
{
    out<<obj.mpg<<":";
        //do what you want
    return out;
}
```