# contents of vector won't print

Tags: c++, vector

So I'm trying to just print the contents of a simple vector, but I'm getting a weird error. Here is the code:

```
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    AIhand[i] = deck[rand() % deck.size()];
    cout << AIhand[i] << endl;
}
```

'deck' is a vector of a Card class (it's for a card game).
The error is coming from the first '<<' in the cout line. Visual Studio is saying "no operator "<<" matches these operands - operand types are: std::ostream < < Card". I'm posting this as a new question because I have included `<string>`, `<iostream>`, and `using namespace std;`, and those are the usual solutions to people's problems of not being able to print a vector.

As far as I can tell my syntax is right, but I'm relatively new to C++, so it might just be user error.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here's the Card class header file:

```
#ifndef CARD_H_
#define CARD_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Card {
public:
    Card(string newSuit, int newValue);
    string showCard();

private:
    int cardValue;
    string cardSuit;
};


#endif CARD_H_
```

here's the Card .cpp file:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

Card::Card(string newSuit, int newValue) {

    cardValue = newValue;

    cardSuit = newSuit;

}

string Card::showCard(){

    stringstream card;

    card << cardValue << " of " << cardSuit << endl;

    return card.str();
}
```

this is the deck

```
vector<Card> deck;

    for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
            Card cuccos("Cuccos", j);
            deck.push_back(cuccos);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++){
            Card loftwings("Loftwings", j);
            deck.push_back(loftwings);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++){
            Card bullbos("Bullbos", j);
            deck.push_back(bullbos);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++){
            Card skulltulas("Skulltulas", j);
            deck.push_back(skulltulas);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print function for class c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239646/print-function-for-class-c)

Comment: did you define the **<< operator** for the class **AIhand**??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I have ostream and iostream defined in the Card class that the AIhand vector uses

Comment: According to my understanding, deck is a vector of card class, so have you defined `<< operator` for card class?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal I have, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference

Comment: then plz share the whole code of operator overloading and class

Comment: @marina If your question is answered, consider accepting the answer (See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)). Otherwise you should probably improve your question to clarify your current implementation of the output operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are *relatively new to C++*, I think there is a misunderstanding in the comments

> I have ostream and iostream defined in the Card class that the AIhand vector uses
>   [...] but it doesn't seem to have made a difference

what others ask about is, whether you have defined a custom ostream `operator <<` for the `Card` class. What you answer is, that you have included the `ostream` and `iostream` header.

Simple solution: try to print text instead of your `Card` class:

```
cout << AIhand[i].showCard() << endl;
```

More sophisticated solution: inform yourself how to overload the `operator <<` for your card class.

See those related questions for more information:

[Print function for class c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239646/print-function-for-class-c)

[How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)